# How can I add a generic page header with site navigation to an asciidoc document?

Tags: html, css, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm trying to build a basic documentation site using asciidoctor. One thing I am struggling with is how I can inject a standard site header (a banner with a logo and top-level navigation) into each documentation page.

I render my asciidoc directly to html from the command line. I have tried to find a way to somehow inject an extra `div` element and position it fixed at the top, but I can't figure out what mechanism to use for this. My early attempts involved using `docinfo.html` but that gets injected into the html in the `<head>` element, instead of the `<body>`.

I am aware that full-on publication systems like Jekyll allow me to configure "front matter" that can probably take care of this, but I was hoping there was a mechanism or trick using vanilla asciidoctor that can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ted Bergeron* on the Mailing List [mentioned](http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Use-AsciiDoctor-only-for-a-simple-website-tp3681p3689.html) a simple project:

[Demo website](http://tedbergeron.github.io/SiteMadeWithAsciidoctor/) created just using Asciidoctor.

Check the [corresponding repo](https://github.com/tedbergeron/SiteMadeWithAsciidoctor) to see the files and how to create the site (just using one command).

In summary: simply create a header asciidoc file that includes your site nav (in the demo site this is done using table markup), *without* including a level-0 (document) title. Include this header file right at the top in every page of your site. Then render by just running `asciidoctor *.txt` on your project.

Answer (score 1):

**`--embedded` option + simple post processing**

With this option, asciidoctor generates only the interior part of the `<body>` element.

For example:

main.adoc

```
= Super title

== Second level

asdf

== Also second level

qwer
```

then:

```
asciidoctor --embedded main.adoc
```

produces:

main.html

```
<div class="sect1">
<h2 id="_second_level">Second level</h2>
<div class="sectionbody">
<div class="paragraph">
<p>asdf</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sect1">
<h2 id="_also_second_level">Also second level</h2>
<div class="sectionbody">
<div class="paragraph">
<p>qwer</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can then just `cat` a header and closing footer, and you are done.

Tested with Asciidoctor 2.0.10.